# navigation between jsf & jsp

Tags: jsp, jsf, intellij-idea

In simple program the login page write with JSF and other page with JSP Login accurate correct and main page is show but link for other page not work and log this:

```
ERROR:PWC6117 createAccount.jsp not found
```

I'm sure the path is correct and when press Ctrl intelliJ know it. I use Facelets and this is `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you show us the link and the JSP source?

Comment: sure!this is the link in main page
    <a href='createAccount.jsp'>Create New Account</a>. when I don't use jsf page all thing is right!please help!it's important for me!thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

This error message is typical for embedded Jetty server which is not configured with JSP servlet. You have 2 options to solve this problem:

- Configure Jetty to serve JSP as well.
- Do not use JSP. Rename it to `.html` or `.xhtml`.